# How to get original endpoint?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have set proxy for my browser to my application hosted on localhost

this is a short snippet of the program

```
boost::asio::io_service ios;
ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service_,ip::tcp::endpoint("127.0.0.1", 12345))
ip::tcp::socket socket(ios);
acceptor_.async_accept(socket,
                boost::bind(&acceptor::handle_accept,
                     this,
                     boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

where this is my acceptor object.

How could I get origin request destination host and port of request redirected to my application?

Full code is here https://github.com/ArashPartow/proxy/blob/master/tcpproxy_server.cpp

Comment: Implement a proxy protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You're pointing the "full code" link to a github repository from someone else. This code example accepts connections on a local port and will forward them to a remote machine. E.g. a connection on localhost to a remote webserver or a connection on your local port 8080 to a remote webserver.

On its command line, you provide the information where to listen for a connection (local) and where to connect to (remote).

I have a strong feeling you want something else: the inbound connection to *tell you* where to connect to (instead of a fixed remote). That's beyond this simple piece of C++ code.

Comment: It's useful to distinguish the jargon "transparent proxy" (or tunnel/forward, which the sample appears to be) and "application proxy" (which OP seems to be after). Protocols are e.g. SOCKS

Comment: The question is how to get original host and port of request that was send to proxy with some predefined ip and port using boost asio. In the end i what to change content of some requests and all other just forward as is

Comment: Is using tcpwrappers an option?  And, the terminology that @sehe mentions may help to find working implementations.